# looping a SQL insert statement with updating dates

Tags: php, sql, loops

What do I need to do is run insert the same thing into a database only changing the date.

i.e

```
INSERT INTO bs_events
(
    eventDate,
    eventTime,
    title,
    spaces,
    description,
    entryFee,
    payment_required,
    max_qty,
    allow_multiple
) 
VALUES (
    '2011-03-02 00:00:00',
    '10:00',
    'Carpet Cleaner 3000',
    '4',
    'This is rad',
    '25.99',
    '1',
    '1',
    '2'
)
```

So I need to run this loop for a year or month or 2 years and have it add to the database but the date needs to change each day

I've got no idea how I go about making a script to do this so any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: im using cpanel because im not too sure how to install oracle

Comment: using mysql ? then use NOW() function in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example. It does it all in one query.

```
$row = array(
    '2011-03-02 00:00:00',
    '10:00',
    'Carpet Cleaner 3000',
    '4',
    'This is rad',
    '25.99',
    '1',
    '1',
    '2'
);

$rows = array();
$end = new DateTime('2012-01-01');
for($date = new DateTime($row[0]); $date < $end; $date->modify('+1 day')) {
    $row[0] = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $rows[] = sprintf("('%s')", implode("','", $row));
}

$query = 'INSERT INTO bs_events
(
    eventDate,
    eventTime,
    title,
    spaces,
    description,
    entryFee,
    payment_required,
    max_qty,
    allow_multiple
) VALUES '.implode(',', $rows);
```

**Note:** This works because the row data is known... if you accepting user input, make sure you are checking for SQL injection.

Comment: how would i run this scrip? im using mysql

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inserting the date directly maybe you could use `now()`, assuming that it is the current date you want to insert.

Comment: that would mean I have to run this everyday?

Comment: Yes, but I thought that you were doing that anyway?

Comment: If you are using windows you could also use scheduled taks to run the script every day. The easyest way to do this is by creating a shortcut and executing this daily. This means your pc needs to be turned on all the time. I think a better alternative would be to use cron, because that will run on the server. Most unix based hosts have cron installed by default i believe

Comment: i want it to add the same thing into the data base but i want the date to go up by one day every time it adds something for the next year or month.

Answer (score 0):

The following will insert the current date instead of a preset date.  This assumes you're using MySQL.

```
INSERT INTO bs_events
(
    eventDate,
    eventTime,
    title,
    spaces,
    description,
    entryFee,
    payment_required,
    max_qty,
    allow_multiple
) 
VALUES (
    DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),
    '10:00',
    'Carpet Cleaner 3000',
    '4',
    'This is rad',
    '25.99',
    '1',
    '1',
    '2'
);
```

You can create a stored procedure to loop and insert as many as you want starting from today using this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE loopInsert()

BEGIN
    DECLARE a INT DEFAULT 0;
    myloop: LOOP
        INSERT INTO bs_events
(
    eventDate,
    eventTime,
    title,
    spaces,
    description,
    entryFee,
    payment_required,
    max_qty,
    allow_multiple
) 
VALUES (
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL a DAY),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),
    '10:00',
    'Carpet Cleaner 3000',
    '4',
    'This is rad',
    '25.99',
    '1',
    '1',
    '2'
);
        SET a = a + 1;
        IF a = 6 THEN
            LEAVE myloop;
        END IF;
    END LOOP myloop;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you can:

```
CALL loopInsert();
```

And it will insert `a` days starting from today.  The example would insert 6 days.

Comment: how would i loop it though with each loop increasing the date by 1 day

Comment: You can create a stored procedure to loop and insert as many as you want starting from today using this:

Comment: i tried this but i get the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/fevsdiet/public_html/diycarpetcare.co.uk/booking/loop2.php on line 4

Comment: The above code isn't PHP.  It's MySQL.  You would run this at the MySQL CLI.

Comment: ahh i think ive gotten confused. im running cpanel and am trying to run it through that or through a php script